# JBAS014775: New missing/unsatisfied dependencies: ------ jboss.security.security-domain.java ---- WSADRealm

Tags: java, jboss

service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./pcp (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."pcp-online.ear"."pcp.war".deploymentCompleteService]

service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./pcp.realm (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.subunit."pcp-online.ear"."pcp.war".deploymentCompleteService, service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./pcp]

`"{\"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies\" => [\"jboss.deployment.subunit.\\\"pcp-online.ear\\\".\\\"pcp.war\\\".component.JBossUserContainer.CREATE is missing [jboss.security.security-domain.java:/jaas/pcpWSADRealm]\"]}"`

standalone::

```
<security-domain name="pcpWSADRealm">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.PostWSADLoginModule" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="unauthenticatedIdentity" value="guest"/>
                            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/pcp_01_DataSource"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT DISTINCT R.ROLE_NAME, 'Roles' FROM AUTH_ROLE R, AUTH_GROUP G, AUTH_USER U, AUTH_USER_AUTH_GROUP UG, AUTH_ROLE_AUTH_GROUP GR  WHERE U.USER_NAME=? AND U.ID=UG.MEMBERS AND UG.GROUPS=G.ID AND G.ID=GR.GROUPS AND GR.ROLES = R.ID"/>
                            <module-option name="projectCode" value="T026"/>
                            <module-option name="keyStore" value="C:/post/app-rep/pcp-v000202-online-ld-node1/configuration/client.keystore"/>
                            <module-option name="url" value="https://webservices.netpost/WSBPGServices/WSADServices.asmx"/>
                            <module-option name="debug" value="true"/>
                            </login-module>
                        </authentication>
                      </security-domain>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can it be any server.xml file problem